# Geting img url and video url from a string

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a string of html

```
<img alt='' src='http:\/\/1.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9ed48ee692d84679c0aa2509985a4c74?s=96&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D96&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-96 photo' height='96' width='96' \/>
```

and I need only to extract the url from it.

Similarly I have this json

```
  [{"ID":1,"post_author":"1","post_date":"2014-04-17 16:09:47","post_date_gmt":"2014-04-17 16:09:47","post_content":"Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!\r\n\r\n&lt;iframe id=\"viddler-ce3d9b65\" src=\"\/\/www.viddler.com\/embed\/ce3d9b65\/?f=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;player=full&amp;secret=53324891&amp;disablebackwardseek=0&amp;disableseek=0&amp;disableforwardseek=0&amp;loop=0&amp;nologo=0&amp;hd=0\" width=\"437\" height=\"288\" frameborder=\"0\" mozallowfullscreen=\"true\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"true\"&gt;&lt;\/iframe&gt;\r\n\r\n&nbsp;","post_title":"Hello world!","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","post_password":"","post_name":"hello-world","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2014-05-09 09:35:11","post_modified_gmt":"2014-05-09 09:35:11","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/neevo.simple-task.com\/?p=1","menu_order":0,"post_type":"post","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"2","filter":"raw"}]
```

and need to extract only the links to the videos in src.

How do I do that?

update:
this resolved the img scr problem

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($ava);
        $url =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: Where is your attempt

Comment: Please provide some more details of what you need

Comment: sry for the mess, this is how it should look

Comment: Have you tried something to get these ?

Comment: i did preg_match but not sure how to wright it correctly

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing a bit better, because at first glance it looks like you want to do some JavaScript manipulation on the first bit of code (but you'd need to submit that to php in a POST or GET request), and some JSON parsing in the second bit (within php). Both of which are highly documented. A bit of background info might help. Along with what you have tried so far?

Comment: i have 2 variables  one that gets the avatar and one that gets all posts by the users, i am writing a json rest api code that returns this values, but atm i need only the avatar url and the viddler video src taken out of the variables so i can pass them on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this in php, to be able to extract the JSON information you want, you just simple have to decode it into a php array and then pull out the part you need. So for example:

```
$json = your_json_feed;
$data = json_decode($json);
$video_url_tmp = $data["post_content"];
```

That will make `$video_url_tmp` contain:

```
Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!\r\n\r\n&lt;iframe id=\"viddler-ce3d9b65\" src=\"\/\/www.viddler.com\/embed\/ce3d9b65\/?f=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;player=full&amp;secret=53324891&amp;disablebackwardseek=0&amp;disableseek=0&amp;disableforwardseek=0&amp;loop=0&amp;nologo=0&amp;hd=0\" width=\"437\" height=\"288\" frameborder=\"0\" mozallowfullscreen=\"true\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"true\"&gt;&lt;\/iframe&gt;\r\n\r\n&nbsp;
```

Which is the part of the JSON feed that you want, that has the URL. Then you'll need a RegEx to pull out the section that you need. It might be easier to RegEx `"id=\"viddler-ce3d9b65\"` part out, and then figure out how viddler creates its links/embeds/whatever and the form it yourself.

Hope this helps you out.

For reference`json_decode`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Just thought I'd share too, this RegEx gets that section I mentioned above `$matched = preg_replace("/\w{7}-......../", $video_url_tmp, $matches)`. The RegEx by itself is: `/\w{7}-......../` see: http://regexr.com/396m1